# How to convert a docbook from version 4.3 to 5

Tags: xsd, docbook, docbook-5

Is there an automated way (or with minimal manual corrections) of converting docbook 4.3 books to the latest DocBook 5?

Answer (score 2):

Would this tool included work for you?

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/docbook5/web/auto-4-5.html

http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.1b7/tools/db4-upgrade.xsl